# Spring Actuator Mongo Status Is Inaccurate on PCF Cloud

Tags: spring, spring-boot, monitoring

I have setup spring actuator to report back health metrics. I have specifically enabled mongo health:

```
management:
  health:
    mongo:
      enabled: true
    rabbit:
      enabled: true
  security:
    enabled: false

endpoints:
  health:
    sensitive: false
```

However if I hit the /health endpoint, the mongo status is always UP even though I completely remove the mongo service from pcf that is attache do my application.

I always get this response:

```
"mongo": {
    "status": "UP",
    "version": "3.2.1"
  }
```

That is completely wrong correct? Upon removing the service, the status must change to "DOWN"

Comment: how are you hooking into/removing the MongoDB service?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I am attaching the mongo managed service through PCF.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the application from PCF completely and redeploying after updating the manifest to remove the mongoDB service?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Our application wont startup if mongo is down. By the way I did not touch manifest. I just manually deleted the service on PCF dashboard.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe The idea was that Actuator should be able to detect it has died down and report the status accordingly.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your question? 

"However if I hit the /health endpoint, the mongo status is always *false* even though I completely remove the mongo service from pcf that is attache do my application."

Is it always false or always true?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe sorry it is always true or UP even if I delete it completely